# How can I filter a wordlist based on multiple characters in shared positions?

Tags: unix

I have a very large wordlist. How can I use Unix to find instances of multiple words fitting specific character-sharing criteria? For example, I want Words 1 and 2 to have the same fourth and seventh characters, Words 2 and 3 to have the same fourth and ninth characters, and Words 3 and 4 to have the same second, fourth, and ninth characters.

Example:

```
aaadiigjlf
abcdefghij
aswdofflle
bbbbbbbbbb
bisofmlwpa
fsbdfopkld
gikfkwpspa
hogkellgis
```

might return

```
abcdefghij
aaadiigjlf
fsbdfopkld
aswdofflle
```

Something like

```
grep '...d..g'  somefile
```

would only work for specific characters, but I need it to work for any shared characters in certain positions; I don't have specific characters (like "d" and "g" as given in the example) in mind. Also, I'd like it to be able to return words that don't fit ALL of the criteria; e.g. in the example given, Words 1 and 4 share a fourth character, but not necessarily the second, seventh, and ninth. With the program I'm running in its finished form, I'm expecting it to return a very small list of words (probably only ten) based on nine strict character-sharing criteria.

EDIT: Due to some confusion in other forums, I've added this clarification. Here's the problem exactly how I was given it.

I am given a wordlist and told that there are ten ten-letter words in the list that can fit into a grid like so:

```
-112--3---
---2--3-4-
-5-2----4-
-5-2--6-4-
75-2--6---
75---8----
7----8----
79---8----
-9--0-----
-9--0---xx
```

Every word reads across. Every space with the same digit (and x) occupying it (all the 1s, all the 2s, etc.) is the same letter (different digits could potentially be the same letter, though not necessarily).